# How to style a button inside an input tag

Tags: html, css, href

Hey im trying to change this (working) line of code here:

```
     *<a href="DPS_Guitarspg3.html">        
        <button style="background-color:rgb(0,0,5)"; type="button"> <p style="color:rgb(111,0,100);">  Guitars</p></button> </a>*
```

Into an equivalent statement w this kind of format(utilizing a class) here:

```
*<a href="DPS_Guitarspg3.html">
<input type="button" class="inline" id="redirectButtons">
</a>*
```

My question is how/where to type in the colored text("Guitars") used in the aforementioned code block in the latter code block.  Sorry if this is a bad question, I am awful with HTML.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, paragraphs can't be children of buttons.

Comment: I think youre looking for the **value** attribute; Example: `<input type="button" class="inline" id="redirectButtons" value="Guitars">`

Comment: how about using only anchor tag then create a class to look like a button.

Comment: If what you're asking for is only to know how to style the button, simply use CSS. In your CSS file, set your `button`'s class properties as you want them. Checkout http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_buttons.asp to see available CSS options for buttons.

Comment: You have a button inside a link.  If you want a button just use a button.  If you want a hyperlink then use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, you can style the `<a>` tag to look/act like a button. Just use the `:hover` and `:active`, like this

```css
.aBtn{
  padding:5px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(111,0,100);
  background-color:rgb(0,0,5);border:1px solid transparent;
}
.aBtn:hover {color:white;}
.aBtn:active{border:1px solid orange;}
```

```html
<a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg3.html">Guitars</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a button to function as a hyperlink. To give you full styling control over the button, you could make the button an image file and put the image file inside your hyperlink.

```
<a href="DPS_Guitarspg3.html">
  <img src="image-of-button.png">
</a>
```

Alternatively, you could use a front-end library like Bootstrap.